# Select all record inserted or updated by last day or last hour from all table in particular database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get all the data that are inserted or updated by last hour or even by last day from all table in a particular database.

Comment: Can you share any code with us?  Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Create a server audit for the database instance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions#database-level-audit-actions or do it in the backend

Answer (score 0):

It will not happen automatically. You need to enable CDC (Change Data Capture) for your database.

> Change data capture provides historical change information for a user
>   table by capturing both the fact that DML changes were made and the
>   actual data that was changed. Changes are captured by using an
>   asynchronous process that reads the transaction log and has a low
>   impact on the system.

For more details check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server)